# HTML Form Alignment Issues in IE

Tags: html, css, forms, doctype

I am facing an issue with displaying form on the link http://senseal.ecentriconline.com/products/multi_primer_overview.html.

It works fine on Firefox, however there is an issue displaying the form on IE. Please check and suggest what needs to be done.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why has this been down voted? It helps when down voting to have reasons. Keep in mind this is a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could also try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your doctype line (first line) to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

This will bring IE out of [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), which is the reason your form is in the wrong place.

Comment: thanks, that resolved. But I still have an issue. The form is being displayed further down in IE, which is not the case with FF. Please suggest.

Comment: [This page](http://senseal.ecentriconline.com/products/multi_primer_overview.html) looks the same in IE8 and Firefox now. Can you double check your problem and explain it, and also say in which browser/version the problem is happening?